# Adjust <p> width to its text content

Tags: html, css

This seems like an easy question but I've been trying to fix it for a couple of hours now and I still cannot find a solution. I have a box with two columns like in here:

```css
p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin-right: 2px;
}

.container {
  padding: 5px;
  width: 90%;
  height: 200px;
  margin: auto;
  border: 1px black solid;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 100%;
}

.half {
  width: 50%;
}

.left-col {
  display: flex;
}

.right-col {
  text-align: right;
}

.tooltip {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px black solid;
  border-radius: 100%;
  width: 14px;
  height: 14px;
  font-size: 12px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="half">
      <div class="left-col">
        <p>Username picked on regitration:</p>
        <div class="tooltip">?</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="half">
      <p class="right-col">
        John WithLongSurname
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The problem is, that when I open the page on mobiles, the text on the left column is too long and it wraps (which is good), but its width still takes a whole column, so the tooltip is not next to the text but in the center of the box (it sticks to the right side of the column). Example:

[image: how it looks now]

I tried to add `width: min-content` to the "label" class, but then the whole paragraph just collapses to the smallest possible width. How can I adjust the width of the paragraph, so it will take only as much width as it needs to, so the tooltip will always be next to it?

Answer (score 1):

It is because you are using `display: flex;` for the `.left-col` class. By default it will distribute the width automatically and evenly.

[image]

Try the styling below to see if it works:

```css
p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin-right: 2px;
}

.container {
  padding: 5px;
  width: 90%;
  height: 200px;
  margin: auto;
  border: 1px black solid;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 100%;
}

.half {
  width: 50%;
}

.left-col {
  display: inline;
}

.right-col {
  text-align: right;
}

.tooltip {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px black solid;
  border-radius: 100%;
  width: 14px;
  height: 14px;
  font-size: 12px;
  display: inline;
}

p.label {
  width: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="half">
      <div class="left-col">
      <p class="label">Username picked on regitration:
         <span class="tooltip">?</span>
      </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="half">
      <p class="right-col">
         John WithLongSurname
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah, but that’s not what I wanted to do. I don’t want to have a tooltip inline with text, but to always keep it on the right, that’s why I used flex. Maybe there's another way for it. With your solution, it’s possible, that text will fit in one line and the tooltip will jump to second one because of lack of space, which doesn’t look very good